# Unable to export to excel whole grid data in kendo grid in angular 6

Tags: angular

Hi i am trying to use the export to excel feature of the kendo grid in angular Following is my  html code

HTML

```html
<button type="button" kendoGridExcelCommand icon="file-excel">Export to Excel</button> 
<kendo-grid-excel fileName="Categories.xlsx" [fetchData]="allData"> 
</kendo-grid-excel>
```

TypeScript

```
class {public gridData:any[];public allData(): ExcelExportData {
  const result: ExcelExportData =  {
      data: process(this.gridData, {
          sort: [{
             field: 'RequestNumber',
             dir:   'asc'
          }]
      }).data,
  };

  return result;
}
```

```
error :Cannot read property 'gridData' of undefined
```

referring this article [Kendo Export](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/export/excel-export/#toc-exporting-specific-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "kendo-grid-excel" component needs to be within the Grid component, and "this" object should point to the actual component in the "allData" method - either bind it in the constructor:

```
constructor() {
    this.allData = this.allData.bind(this);
}
```

... or use an arrow function:

```
public allData = () => {
  // "this" will be the expected object here
}
```